# Phantom RStudio Errors

Tags: r, rstudio, macos-sierra

I'm encountering some really odd behavior with [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) `version 1.0.136` and [r](/questions/tagged/r) `version 3.3.2`, which unfortunately does not lend itself to a reproducible example.

Whenever I force quit an [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) project, I start getting these weird phantom error messages as thought [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) is trying to run code which is not longer present in the project. This happens whenever I type anything in a saved script in the editor.

Does anyone have any thoughts about how I might identify the root cause of this error? Or alternately how I could completely delete everything [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) knows about the pre-crash project?

**Updates**

It is somewhat code independent and has happened on a few projects. I don't actually see the code which it is trying to run, but only the error message which results, which is typically trying to load a file which doesn't exist, or calling a function which hasn't been loaded into memory. I tried the following things:

- Deleting the `.rproj` file and starting a new project in the same folder (no change)
- Reinstalling `R` (no change)
- Reinstalling `RStudio` (no change)
- Upgrading to `Sierra` (no change)
- Moving all files in a project to a new project in a new folder (problem solved, but re-occurs if there is a subsequent force-quit)
- Switching from a saved file to a new untitled file (problem solved, but re-occurs when new file is saved)
- Turning off "Restore previously open source documents at startup" (This seemed to have solved the problem at one point, but then it returned. So not a fix)
- Deleted `RStudio` and `Rstudio desktop directory` according to these instructions: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554736-How-To-Uninstall-RStudio then reinstalling (Did not fix)
- Currently, when I run a script in a saved script it crashes `RStudio`, when I run it in an untitled file it works. Similarly when I run it in a base `R` console it works.

So I think what's going on is that when `RStudio` quits unexpectedly, there's some reference to the initial file which is loaded by the loading `R` files at startup.

**Edit**

Related errors: 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/220481907-Phantom-error-messages-on-RStudio

Comment: Can you update with some more details? What is the code that RStudio is trying to run, and what error messages are you seeing?

Within the project, there is a hidden folder called `.Rproj.user` -- does moving that out of the way make a difference?

Comment: Just added some comments, removing the .rproj.user file has no effect. But disabling "Restore previously open source documents" fixes the issue.

Comment: Turns out this isn't a fix as the problem as returned.

Comment: One potential culprit is R code related to the graphics device state. Do you by any chance see the error emitted whenever the Plots pane / RStudio IDE is resized? Are you able to call dev.off() to clear the graphics device, and if so, does that make a difference?

Comment: Please add the RStudio version number to your question. (I'm used to seeing phantom warnings in RStudio. which are probably related to the magic it does with the documentation.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've added R and RStudiuo version numbers.

Comment: Perhaps a good question for RStudio? Have a look [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200321257-Running-a-Diagnostics-Report). Perhaps also add a tag for your OS.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the problem it seems that Rstudio is trying to run a code that does not exist or depends on packages that are no longer installed. But if the errors only happen when you start typing, it might be due to code diagnostics that runs in the background which is triggered as you type.

try to navigate to **tools -> global options -> code -> diagnostics** and uncheck the following:

- Show diagnostics for R
- Show diagnostics whenever source files are saved
- Show diagnostics after keyboard is idle for a period of time

[In`rstudion 1.3` and newer](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/02/18/rstudio-1-3-preview-configuration/), you can further set the [`background_diagnostics`](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/latest/session-user-settings.html#session-user-settings) `false` by modifying the `rstudio-prefs.json` file. It can be found in `AppData/Roaming/RStudio` on Windows and `~/.config/rstudio` on other systems.

Answer (score -3):

I had the file error when using Rmarkdown in Rstudio. I don't know if it's your case, but my problem was not changing the wd correctly (when I tried no errors wore messaged but using getwd() it didn't change).

In this case, the solution was to set root in Rmarkdown settings with the code

````
```{r setup}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = 'C:/the-desired-path')

```
````

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - the asker is getting 'phantom error messages', whereas your error is expected behaviour.